# Shiny UI Not appearing

Tags: r

So I have a shiny UI that will not display when in a loop, but when put outside of the loop it runs. Is there something I need to do? Everything else is running within the loop but it doesn't stop to open the UI. This happens with or without the launch.browser option included.

For example:

```
if (x > 10) {
  .
  .
    
    # Define UI ----
    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Brands To Match To"),
        mainPanel(
          hr("Common User Entered Words:"),
          hr(),
          x <- (paste(commonnames, collapse = ", ")),
          hr(),
          uiOutput("CheckBox"),
          actionButton("save", "Save")
        )
      )
    
    # Define server logic ----
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      words <- reactiveValues(words = list())
      
      observeEvent(input$save, {
        stopApp()
      })
      
      output$CheckBox <- renderUI({
        lapply(seq_along(vector), function(i) {
          textInput(inputId=paste0("word",i), label=vector[i])
        })
      })
      
      observe({
        assign("words", list(
          word1 = input$word1,
          word2 = input$word2,
          word3 = input$word3,
          word4 = input$word4,
          word5 = input$word5,
          word6 = input$word6,
          word7 = input$word7,
          word8 = input$word8,
          word9 = input$word9,
          word10 = input$word10,
          word11 = input$word11,
          word12 = input$word12,
          word13 = input$word13,
          word14 = input$word14,
          word15 = input$word15,
          word16 = input$word16,
          word17 = input$word17,
          word18 = input$word18,
          word19 = input$word19,
          word20 = input$word20
        ), envir = .GlobalEnv)
      })
      
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
      })
    }
    
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,options=c(launch.browser = rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))
    
}
```

version:
_
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          2.2
year           2022
month          10
day            31
svn rev        83211
language       R
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to make your UI conditional. Have you tried rendering your UI on the server? This example is from shiny.rstudio.com. You can build the x > 10 condition into the renderUI.

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("moreControls")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("n", "N", 1, 1000, 500),
      textInput("label", "Label")
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```